# This message always refers to index problems? IndexError: index out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

Why do I get this message?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\Lake2\Mainloop2.py", line 46, in <module>

Q[i+1]=Qn(HSR[i],TD[i],FW[i],TempLake[i][0])

IndexError: index out of bounds



Nlayers=23
N=365

HSR=Hsr(rad)
TD=Td(air,neb)
FW=Fw(wind)

def main_loop(Z,z,Areat0,Areat1,TempLake,wind,Q0,Q1):
    n=TempLake.size
    var00=Imp_scheme(Q0,Q1,z,Areat0,Areat1,Z,TempLake,wind)
    var01=fix_profile(n,var00,Areat0)
    return var01

TempLake=np.zeros((N,Nlayers))
TempLake[0]=T0

Q=np.zeros(N)
Q[0]=0.0
for i in xrange(N):
    Q[i+1]=Qn(HSR[i],TD[i],FW[i],TempLake[i][0])
    TempLake[i+1]=main_loop(Z,z,Areat0,Areat1,TempLake[i],wind[i],Q[i],Q[i+1])
```

Comment: +1 for descriptive variables and easy to understand code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xrange(N)` gives you values from 0 to N-1.  You are adding one to it, so you access `Q` at indices 1 through N.  But `Q` only has N elements, so N is one more than the highest index, N-1.

Answer (score 0):

In the last iteration of the for loop, the program tries to access Q[i+1], which is Q[N]. Q's size is N, but with indices starting at 0, Q[N-1] is really the last item.